# sequelize nodejs Inner-join with 3 tables?

Tags: sql, node.js, join, sequelize.js, inner-join

This is my native query it includes 2 inner joins. I can write this is one after another.But I want to write this query from nodejs Sequelize.

```
SELECT * 
FROM video_refs r
JOIN accepts a ON a.ComplaintId = r.complaint_id
JOIN vehicles v ON v.acceptId = a.id
WHERE v.vehicleNumber = 'BG345'
```

I tried but this Video_Ref part not working

```
  const foundVehicleList =await Vehicle.findAll({
                where: {
                    vehicleNumber:'BG1234',
            
                },
                include: [                                               
                      { model: Accept, as: 'Accept', attributes: []},   
                      { model: Video_Ref, as: 'Video_Ref', attributes: []},   
                ],
                attributes: [
                    
                  [Sequelize.literal('Accept.ComplaintId'),'ComplaintId']
                ]
    
            });
```

These are the relation

```
db.Complaint.hasOne(db.Video_Ref,{foreignKey: 'complaint_id', sourceKey: 'id'});
db.Video_Ref.belongsTo(db.Complaint,{foreignKey: 'complaint_id', targetKey: 'id'});

db.Complaint.hasOne(db.Accept,{foreignKey: 'ComplaintId ', sourceKey: 'id'});
db.Accept.belongsTo(db.Complaint,{foreignKey: 'ComplaintId ', targetKey: 'id'});

db.Accept.hasMany(db.Vehicle, {foreignKey: 'acceptId', sourceKey: 'id'});
db.Vehicle.belongsTo(db.Accept, {foreignKey: 'acceptId', sourceKey: 'id'});

db.Complaint.hasOne(db.Accept,{foreignKey: 'ComplaintId', sourceKey: 'id'});
db.Accept.belongsTo(db.Complaint,{foreignKey: 'ComplaintId ', targetKey: 'id'});
```

Comment: This is definitely possible using `sequelize`.  It might, however, help if you included any `.findAll` queries you have tried so far, as well as the output you would like vs the output you're receiving.  Also, it's easier for someone to help if you were to include minimum `sequelize` model definitions for `video_refs`, `accepts`, and `vehicles`.  This would remove any ambiguity from the question.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for stuff to try, the sequelize docs on `include` statements, which get serialized to `joins`, can be found in the chapter on eager loading [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html).

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer like

```
SELECT vf.id,vf.reference FROM video_refs vf INNER JOIN complaints c ON vf.`complaint_id` = c.`id` INNER JOIN Accepts a ON c.`id` = a.`ComplaintId` INNER JOIN vehicles vh ON a.`id` = vh.`acceptId` AND vh.`vehicleNumber` = 'BG1234' AND vh.`createdAt` >= '2021-09-06 09:11:38'

const VideoRefList=await Video_Ref.findAll({
            include : [
                {
                    model: Complaint,
                    required: true,
                    attributes: [],
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: Accept,
                            required: true,
                            attributes: [],
                            include : [
                                {
                                    model: Vehicle,
                                    required: true,
                                    attributes: [],
                                    where: {
                                        vehicleNumber:'BG1234',
                                        createdAt: {
                                            [Op.gte]: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()
                                        }
                                    },
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
                attributes: [
                    'id',
                    'reference'
                ]

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to accomplish a sequelize nodejs Inner-join with 3 tables.  I join team with the user and team member tables

'''
const members = teams.findAll({
include:
[
{ model: user, as: "owner" },
{ model: team_member, as: "members", include: [user] },
],
});

'''